# Unity Swipe Controls

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, swipe

I am currently building a game in Unity intending for android devices. Right now for development purposes I am coding by the keyboard controls. What would be the simplest and effective way of approaching the actions when the screen is swiped? I want to access the events screen is swiped left right back or front.

Comment: You didn't post any code

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask], [tour] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to plug into the drag (and other) events is by using EventTrigger component on a UI element (for example Image)

[image]

Comment: Is this a standard asset component?